# Running Tooltwist Controller from the command line - Ruby error

Tags: tooltwist

I am trying to run the Tooltwist Controller from the command line using:

./ttc/config/bin/checkLaunchpad.sh controllerTest

But got below error:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- xmlsimple (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
        from /tooltwist/tooltwist_osx_7.0/devel/ttc/config/bin/checkLaunchpad.rb:21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ToolTwist controller uses a Ruby script to determine which version of payloads should be used, and to synchronize the git caches. This script uses a Ruby gem (like a library) to parse the config files' XML. To install this gem, simply type this on the command line:

> gem install xml-simple